# Regex for mobile number make parathesis as optional for country code and dashes, dots and spaces are optional

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

```
^(?([0-9]{3})?)[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$
```

i am trying to use this regex to validate mobile number i want to allow below formats

```
1234567890
123-456-7890
123.456.7890
123 456 7890
(123)4567890
(123)-456-7890
(123).456.7890
(123) 456 7890
```

please help to correct the regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make use of a capturing group with a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to get consistent delimiters and an alternation to get either the version with or without parenthesis so that for example `123-456.7890` or `(123-456-7890` is not a valid match.

```
^(?:\(\d{3}\)([-. ]?)\d{3}\1\d{4}|\d{3}([-. ]?)\d{3}\2\d{4})$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\(\d{3}\)` Match `(`, 3 digits and `)`
  - `([-. ]?)` Capture **group 1**, optionally match either `-` `.` or space
  - `\d{3}\1\d{4}` Match 3 digits, backreference to group 1 and 4 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `\d{3}` Match 3 digits
  - `([-. ]?)` Capture **group 2**, optionally match either `-` `.` or space
  - \d{3}\2\d{4}` Match 3 digits, backreference to group 2 and 4 digits
- `)`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A1a6P8/1)

```js
let pattern = /^(?:\(\d{3}\)([-. ]?)\d{3}\1\d{4}|\d{3}([-. ]?)\d{3}\2\d{4})$/;
[
  "1234567890",
  "123-456-7890",
  "123.456.7890",
  "123 456 7890",
  "(123)4567890",
  "(123)-456-7890",
  "(123).456.7890",
  "(123) 456 7890",
  "(123-456-7890",
  "123-456.7890"
].forEach(s => console.log(s + " --> " + pattern.test(s)));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use this

```
^\(?[0-9]{3}\)?[\-\.\s]?\(?[0-9]{3}\)?[\-\.\s]?\(?[0-9]{4}\)?$
```

Test it here https://regex101.com/

Comment: ```^\(?[0-9]{3}\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$```
this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

`()` are special character is regex so you need to escape them, to make it optional you can use `?`

You can change your pattern to this

```
^([0-9]{3}|\([0-9]{3}\))([-. ]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})$
```

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/XOvztU/3/)

```js
const regex = /^([0-9]{3}|\([0-9]{3}\))([-. ]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})$/gm;
const str = `1234567890
123-456-7890
123.456.7890
123 456 7890
(123)4567890
(123)-456-7890
(123).456.7890
(123) 456 7890
(123 456 7890
(123 456 7890
123-456.7890`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
    console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
  });
  console.log('------')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably like this

```
var patt = new RegExp('\\(?[0-9]{3}\\)?[.-\\s]?[0-9]{3}[.-\\s]?[0-9]{4}');
```